# How to check collection for null in spring data jpa @Query with in predicate

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have this query in my spring data jpa repository:

```java
@Query("SELECT table1 FROM Table1 table1 "
   + "INNER JOIN FETCH table1.error error"
   + "WHERE table1.date = ?1 "
   + "AND (COALESCE(?2) IS NULL OR (table1.code IN ?2)) "
   + "AND (COALESCE(?3) IS NULL OR (error.errorCode IN ?3)) ")
List<Table1> findByFilter(Date date, List<String> codes, List<String> errorCodes);
```

When I run this query, it shows me this error by console:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
      Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
      Position: 1642
```

However if I run the query without the `(COALESCE (?2) IS NULL OR` part, just the `table1.code IN ?2`, it does work

Does anyone know what this error could be due to?

Comment: Coalesce and List does not work

Comment: @SimonMartinelli So how could I do it?

Comment: You will have to do a dynamic query if you want to check for empty lists. Use Specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `COALESCE` with one parameter does not make sense. This is an abbreviated CASE expression that returns the first non-null operand. (See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_coalesce_expressions))
2. I would suggest you to use [named parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) instead of position-based parameters. As it's stated in the documentation this makes query methods a little error-prone when refactoring regarding the parameter position.
3. As it's stated in [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-in-predicate) related to the IN predicate:

> The list of values can come from a number of different sources. In the `constructor_expression` and `collection_valued_input_parameter`, *the list of values must not be empty; it must contain at least one value.*

4. I would suggest you also avoid to use outdated `Date` and use instead java 8 Date/Time API.

So, taken into account all above, you should use a dynamic query as it was suggested also in comments by @SimonMartinelli. Particularly you can have a look at the [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications).

Assuming that you have the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
public class Error
{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String errorCode;

   // ...
}

@Entity
public class Table1
{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private LocalDateTime date;
   private String code;

   @ManyToOne
   private Error error;

   // ...
}
```

you can write the following specification:

```java
import javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;

public class TableSpecs
{

   public static Specification<Table1> findByFilter(LocalDateTime date, List<String> codes, List<String> errorCodes)
   {
      return (root, query, builder) -> {
         root.fetch("error", JoinType.LEFT);
         Predicate result = builder.equal(root.get("date"), date);
         
         if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(codes)) {
            result = builder.and(result, root.get("code").in(codes));
         }
         if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(errorCodes)) {
            result = builder.and(result, root.get("error").get("errorCode").in(errorCodes));
         }
         return result;
      };
   }
}

public interface TableRepository extends CrudRepository<Table1, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Table1>
{
   default List<Table1> findByFilter(LocalDateTime date, List<String> codes, List<String> errorCodes)
   {
      return findAll(TableSpecs.findByFilter(date, codes, errorCodes));
   }
}
```

and then use it:

```java
List<Table1> results = tableRepository.findByFilter(date, Arrays.asList("TBL1"), Arrays.asList("ERCODE2")));
```